# Typescript Breakpoints Fail when using Chutzpah

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, unit-testing, chutzpah

Per Chutzpah documentation on Github on the `Compile` configuration element.

> This setting lets you describe in the Chutzpah.json file how to execute a command which can compile your source files to .js files. You tell Chutzpah what to execute and some information about what your executable does (like where to find the generated .js files). Then after running the executable Chutzpah can associate each source file with each output file to still give the nice behavior of mapping tests back to their original files.

I interpret this to mean that the `js.map` files are utilized properly and therefore breakpoints in the original TS source should work.

Everything else is working properly.

When I place a breakpoint in a Typescript unit test, it fails to break when `Test->Debug->All Tests`.

It also fails to break when right clicking and selecting the Chutzpah menu item to `Open in Browser`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version 4.1.0 of Chutzpah adds integrated [VS debugging](https://github.com/mmanela/chutzpah/wiki/Debugging-Unit-Tests). You can set breakpoints in your JS files (TypeScript too if you generated source maps) and launch using the Visual Studio Debugger from the context menu:

[image]

Comment: Is the support for chrome and phantomjs planned, too?

Answer (score 0):

Per the author of Chutzpah.

[Chutzpah does not support the VS debugger.](https://github.com/mmanela/chutzpah/issues/372)

The mapping files enable clicking on Test Explorer and placing focus on the correct test in your TypesScript file.